# Association and TemplateApply problem in associations section of The Wolfram Language:Fast introduction to programmers

Tags: associations

I am going over [The Wolfram Language:Fast introduction to programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/). In the [associations section](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/associations/), following question and answer is given

> Which of the following applies a template to make a string with appetizer and dessert from the association

```
 meal=<|"appetizer" →"nachos", "salad" → "spinach", "dessert" → "chocolate"|>
 TemplateApply["The appetizer is `appetizer` and the dessert is `dessert`.", meal]
```

But in my mathematica notebook, I am getting errors from the above two lines of code.

> Incompatible elements in Join .... cannot be joined.

But according to web site, this is correct answer. Where is my mistake?

According @N0va, this is a typo. See below screenshot.

[image: Demo of Typo]

Comment: One of the most unfortunate and hard to detect Typos I have seen on this page: Somehow the arrows in `meal` are wrong while being displayed correctly. Using this should work `meal = <|"appetizer" -> "nachos", "salad" -> "spinach", 
   "dessert" -> "chocolate"|>;`.

Comment: That is correct, with your comment it works. Please enter it as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: But this is an stopping error for beginners. Both outputs are hard to distinguish for beginners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a short story short: use `->` for the Association:

```
mealWorking=<|"appetizer"->"nachos","salad"->"spinach","dessert"->"chocolate"|>;
TemplateApply["The appetizer is `appetizer` and the dessert is `dessert`.",meal]
```

generates the desired output:

```
The appetizer is nachos and the dessert is chocolate.
```

---

To make a short story long and to elaborate a bit on my comment on OPs question: This is one of the worst (in the sense of hard to detect) and unfortunate typos I have seen. The problem can not be fixed when looking at the `InputForm`

```
meal=<|"appetizer" →"nachos", "salad" → "spinach", "dessert" → "chocolate"|>
```

only. The output

```
Association["appetizer" \[RightArrow] "nachos", "salad" \[RightArrow] "spinach", "dessert" \[RightArrow] "chocolate"]
```

however shows the problem: this is not a valid `Association` but the pasted text here already spoils the conclusion which is not so obvious inside a notebook:

[image: Output]

The arrows in the definition are `\[RightArrow]` and they should be `\[Rule]` (equivalent to `->`) so the solution is

```
mealWorking = <|"appetizer" -> "nachos", "salad" -> "spinach",  "dessert" -> "chocolate"|>
```

looking like this in the notebook

[image: wokring]

Hard to detect since inside a notebook Mathematica displays `\[Rule]` and `\[RightArrow]`  using its *Wolfram System fonts* which do not distinguish between the two symbols. One way to detect the difference is looking at the cell expression (select the input cell an use the menu item `Cell->Show Cell Expression` or its shortcut) to display

[image: Cell expression]

or copy the plain text to an editor outside of Mathematica. To be honest I think Mathematica should indicate things like this as syntax errors but sadly it does not.